# Switch in Xamarin.Android not rendering its UI

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Android project that has been in development for awhile.  I went to use my first Android Switch control yesterday.  When the UI rendered on my device (I don't use Xamarion.Android preview editor cause it continually crashes VS).  It only showed off/on text, and no UI for the switch control at all.  This seemed to happen regardless of what width/height I specified for the control etc.

I created a new Android project, dropped the switch on and it renders fine.  I then changed the API level to match my API level (21) and it rendered a bit differently, but again rendered fine.

After much debugging and frustration I discovered that if I implement by own custom drawables for the Thumb and Track that the UI seems to function.

So I was wondering:  Has anyone run into this before?  Do we know what the cause is?

I wanted to document this in case anyone else ran into problems.

Someone requested layout code.  There's not much, but here it is:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content>
<Switch
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have any layout code you can share?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this as I am having the same issue now?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I managed to get this figured out, then forgot to update this.  Unfortunately I couldn't get it working through Xamarin.  Something was messed up and I didn't know what it was and couldn't get an answer from anyone.  So:  I drew it myself (which I ended up needing to do anyway for my app).

In my layout for the switch I set these two drawables:

```
android:thumb="@drawable/SwitchThumbTrack"
android:track="@drawable/SwitchTrack"
```

Then in my code when someone toggles it I have a drawable for SwitchTrackOn as well.  If you want, here's some code to make it kind of look like an iOS switch:

SwitchThumbTrack.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
   <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
   <size android:width="30dp" android:height="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

SwitchTrack

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
   <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
   <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff"/>
   <solid android:color="#0000FF" />
   <size android:width="80dp" android:height="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

SwitchTrackOn

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/White"/>
  <solid android:color="#4ED164" />
  <size android:width="80dp" android:height="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

Hope this helps!

James

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding the following worked:

```
android:minWidth="100dp"
android:minHeight="50dp"
```